# can I drive a uk registered car with my greek driving license?

Tags: united-kingdom

Just moved to the UK for a maximum period of 12 months.
If I buy a second hand car can I drive it using my greek driving license?
Does the license need revision or accepted as is? How is regulated the insurance policy regarding foreign citizens/ driving licenses?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether your Greek licence allows you to drive in the UK here https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence  On the facts given in the question, Yes, you can drive for up to 12 months with your Greek driving licence. Other requirements are that your vehicle must:
- be registered with the DVLA
- have up to date vehicle tax (you will need to arrange this when you buy the car)
- have a current MOT certificate (if your vehicle needs one - typically those over 3 years old)
- be roadworthy.
You must also have a minimum of third party insurance that covers your use of the vehicle https://www.gov.uk/legal-obligations-drivers-riders

Automatic number plate recognition (ANPR) is widely used in the UK to help enforce driving laws https://www.police.uk/information-and-advice/automatic-number-plate-recognition/

You should also make sure you are aware of drink-driving restrictions, speed limits on the various road categories, bus lane and parking restrictions etc, and the penalties for infringement.

Comment: It is probably worth updating this answer to say that on the facts given, the OP *can* drive with their Greek driving license for 12 months.

Comment: @Martin Bonner Thanks, have edited this into the answer